# jquery - add animation to background image change

Tags: jquery, css, animation, background

I'm using a script that changes the background image of a div (class .hmcarousel) and carousels through 5 images - it seems to work OK. However I need to add an animated fade  effect to each transition (which at the moment is and immediate change) - but do not know what part of the function to add the animation script to. Many thanks for helping out.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  var body = $('.hmcarousel');
  var backgrounds = new Array(
    "url(soml_slider_1.jpg)",
    "url(soml_slider_2.jpg)",
    "url(soml_slider_3.jpg)",
    "url(soml_slider_4.jpg)",
    "url(soml_slider_5.jpg)"
  );
  var current = 0;
  function nextBackground() {
    body.css(
      'background',
      backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]
    );
    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
  }
  setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
  body.css('background', backgrounds[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the effect in three simple steps.
1) Fadeout the div
2) Change the background
3) Fadein the div

So this will look like a fade effect.  So, essentially your function will look like:

```
    function nextBackground() {
body.fadeOut(1000);
body.css(
'background',
backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]
);
body.fadeIn(1000);
setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
}
```

All the best!!! Cheers!